# ¿Cómo valido que exista un archivo en el input de tipo file para poder enviarlo por el formulario?

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito validar que mi input de tipo file contenga un archivo, preferentemente que sea jpg o png.

Esto es lo que he podido hacer hasta ahora, no tengo idea de como trabajar con el input file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Diesan Romero">
  <meta name="description" content="Sube tus imagenes de manera temporal">
  <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
  <title>Imágenes Momentaneas</title>
</head>

<body onload="timer()" oncontextmenu="return false" ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" onkeydown="return false">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <h1><span>Imágenes Momentáneas</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
      <form action="data.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form">
          <h3 class="row justify-content-center mt-5">Seleccione el tiempo en minutos que estará su imagen en línea</h3>
          <div class="row justify-content-center mt-1">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">1</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">5</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">15</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">30</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">60</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
            <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" class="input-file">
            <label for="imagen" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-red js-labelFile">
              <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
              <span class="js-fileName">Elija la imagen a subir</span>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-red" value="Subir Imagen">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="alert alert-success invisible" role="alert">
          La imagen ha sido cargada correctamente, ahora debe subirla.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No se mucho php, ando aprendiendo y se me acaba de dificultar este tema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero para validar que tenga un archivo elegido es checar si no esta vacío, con PHP puede ser así gracias a su propiedad size; para los tipos de archivos puedes hacerlo a través del MIME/TYPE del modo siguiente

1. **$_FILES** Sirve para leer archivos de tipo input
2. **size** Sirve para detectar el peso del archivo subido
3. **type** Sirve para leer el tipo de archivo que esta llegando

   > if ($_FILES['imagen']['size'] != 0 && $_FILES['imagen']['type'] ===
   >   'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['imagen']['type'] === 'image/png')
   >       {
   >           //acciones para mover el archivo
   >       }else {
   >          //algo anda mal
   >       }

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Shadow, tu siempre tan atento. Poco a poco mientras estudio voy aprendiendo. Saludos.